# Why my app crashes, when assigning a weak reference to ui elements?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, tableview

My app crashes when assigning ui elements weak reference in code, though by default when using storyboards ui elements are forced to be assigned weak reference.

```
class UploadContactShowViewController: BasePage,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, DARChatPhoneShowCellDelegate {

    var counter = 0

    var delegate: UploadContactShowViewControllerDelegate?
    var contact: APContact?

    var contactSelected: APContact?
    var contacts: [DARContact] = []
    var selectedContacts: [DARContact]!
    var checkBoxs: [BEMCheckBox]!

    var avatarImageView: UIImageView!
    var fullNameLabel: UILabel!
    var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

Comment: Neither of those is a weak reference

Comment: I don't see any `weak`s

Comment: Further to the two comments above what you have declared there are implicitly unwrapped optionals - optional variables which you are telling the compiler will be set to non-nil values at some point. If you fail to do this the app will crash whenever it tries to use those variables as the assumption is that they are non-nil.

Comment: It's more likely your storyboard referencing outlets are incorrect/non-existent or you're accessing the properties too early before `awakeFromNib` happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Storyboard (or a xib) unarchives the UI elements it adds them as subviews to the existing view. Because of this there is a strong reference (subviews are strongly referenced) and although IBOutlets are weak, there is a strong reference to prevent them from being deallocated.

If you are creating views in code and adding them to `weak` references, unless you have already added them as a subview, there is no reference so nothing is holding onto these UI Items, so they are deallocated.